# bitcoind generating only one block

Tags: bitcoin

I'm working on an implementation to create an altcoin based on Bitcoin 0.15.  Eventually it will be a script that works with the source.

Here is the repo:  https://github.com/openfrdb/clone_coin

The current step is to get the new chainparams.cpp file to work with the regtest network.  I have it accepting a new genesis block and generating the first block in the chain with the new configuration (as shown in the repo).

Now, most of the work was done without any guidance, so might be completely off base, but this tutorial was used as a helper after a while:
http://dillingers.com/blog/2015/04/18/how-to-make-an-altcoin/

Does anyone have any insight as to why only 1 block can be made?  I'm using these commands to generate the first block:

```
./bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=rpcuser -rpcpassword=rpcpass getnewaddress
./bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=rpcuser -rpcpassword=rpcpass generate 1
```

I'm sure it has to do with consensus parameters but not sure where.

This script will be MIT after it is done.  Allowing anyone to easily generate a new altcoin out of Bitcoin, the gold standard.

Comment: After running the above command I started mining and have gotten up to 85 blocks on regtest, so maybe it works.  Need to wait for about 20 more to see. updates to follow.  Thanks to IRC for the direction